# how to use annotation to validate LocalDateTime in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm using the @Valid to validate the RequestBod data, see bellow:

Controller MemberController.java

```
public R<String> addMember(@Valid @RequestBody AddMemberVO memberVO) {
    ...
}
```

Model AddMemberVO.java

```
public class AddMemberVO{
    //Member card start time
    private LocateDateTime startTime;
    
    //Member card end time
    private LocateDateTime endTime;
    
    ...
}
```

For this api, i want to validate the startTime and endTime using annotation.

all date use the same pattern **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**

if input:
{
"startTime":"2021-10-01 **94**:00:00",
"EndTime":"2021-10-01 14:00:00"
}
**except result**: startTime format is invalid.

if input:
{
"startTime":"2021-**19**-01 00:00:00",
"EndTime":"2021-10-01 14:00:00"
}
**except result**: startTime format is invalid.

i found a way - change the startTime and endTime from LocalDateTime to String, but i don't think this is a good idea. because if changed, I should do a lot of things about convert String to LocalDateTime.

is there any other ways to validate this scene(use LocalDateTime) for my code?

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to convert it to a `LocalDateTime` because it is invalid, so how would you validate something that cannot be converted?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes it's invalid.  will get error when deserialize the json.

Comment: Yes you will get an error